# How do I escape a colon included in text in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-update

I have moved a WordPress site from a local server to a remote server and a number of the image paths contained in posts are incorrect.

I want to batch change them by running a search/replace query in phpMyadmin but as the text contains a colon it keeps failing. What is the correct syntax to escape the colon and run the query? This is the query I am trying to run.

```
UPDATE wp_post SET post_contect = REPLACE (post_content, ‘old domain:8888', ‘newdomain.co.uk');
```

Comment: The colon is not in error and does not need escaping, but those quotes are causing errors. Do you see above how the opening single quote is actually a leaning curly quote? The correct character is `'` not `‘`  If you copied this from the web somewhere, you must be very careful with what kinds of quotes appear.

Comment: So `REPLACE (post_content, 'old domain:8888', 'newdomain.co.uk')` would work correctly.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue and I have been able to run the query.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the colon (`:`), it's the fact you're using the wrong quotes - you should use `'` to denote a string literal, not `‘`.

```
UPDATE wp_post 
SET    post_contect = 
       REPLACE (post_content, 'old domain:8888', 'newdomain.co.uk');
```